# Display selected image in a div from image browser in telerik mvc

Tags: telerik-mvc

I have customize a image browser in Telerik Editor MVC. I want to display image in a div when i click on a image in image browser.
how can i do this?

Comment: Create link for a page that binary writes the image as a file download.